# Tkinter - How can i have a Sub-GUI inside a GUI that changes using buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made the Main_GUI and Sub-GUI's separately using Tkinter, My Question is that what can i do to combine them all together.

Here's the design for the layers hierarchy :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMCIx.jpg

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Have you tried doing this? Tkinter has frames that can contain any widgets you want, and you can combine multiple frames in a window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter

Comment: thanks for the resource, got the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/16469825